# jquery scroll up button doesn't appear on the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a scroll up button, this button appear after a scroll down of 700px but for a reason this button it doesn't appear

HTML code to create the button

```
<div id="scroll-top">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-up fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
```

Css code to create the button

```
#scroll-top {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    color:#fdbb45;
    background-color: #006095;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

#scroll-top:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

jQuery code to make a click button and appear after 700px

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Scroll To Top
    var scrollButton = ("#scroll-top");
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log($(this).scrollTop());

        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 700) {
            scrollButton.show();

        } else {
            scrollButton.hide();

        }
        
        //Click On Button To Scroll Up
        scrollButton.click(function () {
            $("html,body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 600);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated: You've nested your click inside the scroll event, so every time the page scrolls you get *another* click handler, it doesn't do much so might not be a problem in this case.

Comment: `var scrollButton = ("#scroll-top");` typo in the question or also in your code?

Comment: Any errors, like `Uncaught TypeError: scrollButton.hide is not a function` ?

Comment: Code works fine after fixing typo: https://jsfiddle.net/pbkfxue4/